# RavenDB 4.x alternatives to EscapeQueryOptions.RawQuery?

Tags: c#, ravendb

In previous versions (3.5) there was the possibility to search using *AND* / *OR* operators across multiple fields transformed in a static index:

```
  var searchString = filter.ToLowerInvariant().Replace(" and ", " AND ").Replace(" or ", " OR ");
                var query = await session.Query<MyAbstractIndexCreationTask.Result, MyAbstractIndexCreationTask>()
                                .Search(element => element.FilterableItems, searchString, escapeQueryOptions: EscapeQueryOptions.RawQuery)
```

With 4.2 I need to rewrite code:

```
var searchString = filter.ToLowerInvariant().Replace(" and ", " AND ").Replace(" or ", " OR ");
                    var query = session.Query<MyAbstractIndexCreationTask.Result, MyAbstractIndexCreationTask>()
                        .Search(element => element.FilterableItems, searchString)
```

where `EscapeQueryOptions.RawQuery` cannot be passed in anymore.
The closest thing I can find is `session.advanced.rawquery` with does not take `AbstractIndexCreationTask` for transformations.

Is there any possiblity to allow users to provide basic *AND* / *OR* filtering?